# NHibernate advanced search headache

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I really believe this is a simple problem, but one of those with a solution that's not obvious to an NHibernate newbie like me...

Here's the deal, I'm conducting my NHibernate-related queries from a data service layer that knows nothing about NHibernate (for separation of concerns). As such, I'm constructing my queries by using LINQ (Sytem.Linq).

I want to search on more than one word. For instance, if someone types in "training excel", then I will search a number of entities and related location entities based on both words.

Here's what my code looks like in my service layer right now:

```
// We are delimiting by spaces and commas.
string delimiterString = " ,";
char[] delimiter = delimiterString.ToCharArray();
IEnumerable<string> words = searchWords.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// Loop through each search word in the collection and apply the "Where" clause to our IQueryable collection:
foreach (string word in words) {
    matches = matches.Where(i => i.Subject.Contains(word)
        || i.Background.Contains(word)
        || i.Summary.Contains(word)
        || i.Organization.Contains(word)
        || i.Locations.Any(l => l.Organization.Contains(word))
        || i.Locations.Any(l => l.City.Contains(word))
    );
}
```

Here's the issue... through viewing my application logs and running NHibernate Profiler, I see that the T-SQL query is correctly being constructed. The search works fine with just one search word passed in. However, if 2 or more words are detected, the last word detected is the only one searched on. For instance, if the search term was **"training excel"**, then, as I step through my code above, both words are correctly added in the loop, but the final T-SQL output has "excel" in both logical where groups in the WHERE clause (i.e. `WHERE course.Subject like ('%' + 'excel' + '%')...... AND course.Subject like ('%' + 'excel' + '%')......`). There should have been "training" in the first group and "excel" in the second group.

It seems like NHibernate is using some sort of query caching for efficiency because the query signature is the same (since we're looping through all the words). Again, I have verified that both words are being used when stepping through my code.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be the common pitfall "access to modified closure". Try

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
  var wordLoopVariable = word; 
  matches = matches.Where(i => i.Subject.Contains(wordLoopVariable)
    || i.Background.Contains(wordLoopVariable)
    || i.Summary.Contains(wordLoopVariable)
    || i.Organization.Contains(wordLoopVariable)
    || i.Locations.Any(l => l.Organization.Contains(wordLoopVariable))
    || i.Locations.Any(l => l.City.Contains(wordLoopVariable))
);
```

And do some googling on closures.

Comment: Wow. In my decade of .NET programming, I don't recall ever getting bitten by this gotcha. Then again, I might have "conveniently" forgotten! Thanks!

Comment: I know! I have Resharper looking over my shoulder all the time. It seems that Microsoft are even considering a breaking change in the `foreach` statement in the next c# release.